# Evernote API findNotesMetadata php

Tags: php, api, laravel, evernote

I am trying to retrieve a list of notes from the Evernote API, and the script I am using returns a screen that says "whoops something went wrong"

```
<?php
$token = 'S=s1:U=904d8:E=152a2ea0df7:C=14b4b38e1d0:P=1cd:A=en-devtoken:V=2:H=c28ff07ca3ee987b8c916cfc0c536e99';

$sandbox = true;
$client = new \Evernote\Client($token, $sandbox);

$notebookGuid = "c1977c63-ffc7-4876-a071-67fd6ea9fd4c";

$filter = new NoteFilter();
 // $filter->notebookGuid = $notebookGuid;
$offset = 0;
$spec = new NotesMetadataResultSpec();
$spec->includeTitle = true;
$spec->includeContentLength = true;
$spec->includeCreated = true;
$spec->includeUpdated = true;
//$spec->includeDeleted = true;
$spec->includeUpdateSequenceNum = true;
$spec->includeNotebookGuid = true;
$spec->includeTagGuids = true;
$spec->includeAttributes = true;
$spec->includeLargestResourceMime = true;
$spec->includeLargestResourceSize = true;

// $resultSpec->includeTitle = true;

$notes = $client->findNotesMetadata($token, $filter, 0, 10,$spec);
```

Comment: Can you provide any error message (type of error, traceback, line number, etc.) from the logs?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should comment out the line where you assign the notebookGuid to filter.

Second, **findNotesMetadata is a method of a NoteStore object**.

So, the last lines should look like that:

```
$noteStore = $client->getNoteStore();

$notes = $noteStore->findNotesMetadata($token, $filter, 0, 10, $spec);
```